# Multiple user accounts android app

Tags: android, authentication, passwords

I'm designing an application for work. For security reasons, we want each employee to have to login to the app with a username and password. Additionally, we want to be able to revoke a specific employee's access if they quit/are fired. So essentially, I want to be able to give each employee a unique username and password for the app, and then be able to invalidate a specific user if necessary. Any suggestions on where to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have done so far and what issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is the very good option in your case. Firebase Auth let users create a username with a password.

Refer this link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: this seems to be the right way to go but I'm having issues getting Firebase to gel with my app. Even after I add the necessary lines of code into my gradle, the IDE still tells me it can't resolve the symbol FirebaseAuth.

Comment: Have you register your app in google firebase console.Link to login google firebase: https://firebase.google.com/ sample app for google firebase auth follow this procedure: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/